# Ubuntu/PHP/MySQL: mysql-functions not working?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu-11.04

i recently installed Ubuntu on my server, replacing Windows. My Website ran fine under Windows/XAMPP, but not with Ubuntu. I tried a simple db-connect:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword") or die ("connection error");
    mysql_select_db("db1", $con) or die ("db selection error");
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM atable");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($qry)) {
        echo $row->id;
    }
?>
```

but when i load the page, nothing happens. php works fine,

```
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

is working as expected...

my (testing purpose) settings are:

- Ubuntu 11.04 and LAMP
- the mysql bind-adress in my.cnf is set to 0.0.0.0
- the host of root-user of mysql is set to %, privileges are granted to *.*
- extension_dir of php5 is set to "/usr/lib/perl5/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so"

what am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is your complete code, but what are you expecting? Your code does not output anything if mysql connection/selecting the db works.

Comment: As Bernhard said the code snippet you posted doesn't output anything, i.e. you're connecting to the db but not issuing any selects/updates etc

Comment: sorry, forgot the rest, edited

Comment: AFAIU, extension_dir should be directory, not *.so file

Comment: you're right, changed that to the directory

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?  I have the exact same problem.  Script works fine on my local Windows development machine but when I upload to the Ubuntu server it fails.  I know my php is setup correctly as I'm able to echo statements out the screen.  I'm also sure my database connection is working because if I use php as a command line script, everything works as expected.  Like you, if I execute the code in the context of Apache, anything before the gets output, but nothing after.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the `php-mysql` package? If not please install it.In ubuntu you will find it in the  Package Manager(search for `php-mysql`) or do

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

After installing restart the webserver if necessary, using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out, what you are doing wrong by looking at the error

```
if ($qry !== false) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($qry)) {
        echo $row->id;
     }
} else echo mysql_errno() . ': ' . mysql_error();
```

But remember, that the query may return an empty set, if your query simply not match any record in your database. In your case when `atable` is empty, of course nothing can get returned.

Comment: tried that, but nothing happens... also tried: `echo "1"; mysql_connect(...); echo "2";`, result is only '1'. i find that strange because the `or die (..)` should echo something, but it just dies quietly

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code to see if you've got mysql support available within Apache and php:

```
<?php
if (function_exists('mysql_connect')) {
    echo "Good<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "Bad.<br />\n";
}
?>
```

If not you'll need to:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

and then **restart Apache** to get the code to work

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Source: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/869918-mysql_connect-function-isnt-working